# Purpose of the 64 bit public key token in .NET Assembly?

Tags: .net

What is the purpose of the 64 bit public key token in .NET Assembly. I understand that the public key corresponding to the private key which is used to sign the assembly is embedded in the assembly itself. What purpose does the 64 bit public key token serve when the public key as a whole is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the fully-qualified name of the assembly -- using the 64-bit token ends up being unique enough to not cause problems, while not making the assembly name overly long.